# Query with different types in GraphQL

Tags: graphql

I have a GraphQL `userType` and `EventType` and on my `userType` I have to make a nested query using `EventType` but I also need to return user information. Since `EventType` doesn't have fields same as user info so to pass my code on testing I had to manually copy-paste `UserType` to `EventType` but I don't want this to solution.

Is there a way to like merge types? I'm using MongoDB as my database so when trying to do a `POPULATE` the user info comes back but GraphQL making it hard.

So this is what I did on `EventType` to pass the test. Under "fixme" I copy the `UserType`:

```
module.exports = {
  EventType: new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Event',
    fields: () => ({
      id: {type: GraphQLID},
      organizerId: {type: new GraphQLList(GraphQLID)},
      title: {type: GraphQLString},
      image: {type: GraphQLString},
      description: {type: GraphQLString},
      location: {type: GraphQLString},
      items: {type: GraphQLInt},
      date: {type: GraphQLString},
      attendeesId: {type: new GraphQLList(GraphQLID)},
      supplies: {type: new GraphQLList(GraphQLString)},
      test: {type: GraphQLString},

      // FIXME: USER TYPES!
     firstName: {type: GraphQLString},
     lastName: {type: GraphQLString},
     email: {type: GraphQLString},
     age: {type: GraphQLInt},
     token: {type: GraphQLString},
     image: {type: GraphQLString},
     phone: {type: GraphQLInt},
     address: {type: GraphQLString},
     // ! TYPE RELATION
     userRelatedToEvent: {
     type: UserType,
     resolve: async (parent, args) => {
       const id = {
         id: parent.organizerId
       };
       return await getCurrentUser(id);
      }
    }
  })
 })
};
```

this is my code on `UserType` that is doing a Type relation on `EventType` see `resolve` prop

```
module.exports = {
 UserType: new GraphQLObjectType({
 name: 'User',
 fields: () => ({
  id: {type: GraphQLID},
  firstName: {type: GraphQLString},
  lastName: {type: GraphQLString},
  email: {type: GraphQLString},
  age: {type: GraphQLInt},
  token: {type: GraphQLString},
  image: {type: GraphQLString},
  phone: {type: GraphQLInt},
  address: {type: GraphQLString},
  eventsId: {type: new GraphQLList(GraphQLID)}, // <-- this will be the query for userRelatedToUser
  statusCode: {type: GraphQLInt},
  isSuccess: {type: GraphQLBoolean},
  msg: {type: GraphQLString},
  test: {type: GraphQLString}, // testing query
  // errors: { type: GraphQ LString },
  eventRelatedToUser: {
    type: require('./eventTypeDef').EventType,
    resolve: async (parent, args) => {
      const event = {
        event: parent.eventsId
      };
      const test = await getEventWithEventId(event); // <-- queries event
      const id = {
        id: test.attendeesId
      };
      const users = await getCurrentUser(id); // <-- user info
      console.log(users);
      return {...users, ...test};
    }
   }
  })
 })
};
```

Comment: Does an event itself have a first name, last name, _etc._, or are those fields copies of the fields on the associated user?

Comment: those are copies. thats what im trying to figure out. to associate both fields. is there such way? @DavidMaze

Comment: The ordinary GraphQL way would be to not have those fields directly; a query like `someEvent { user { firstName } }` would retrieve it.